# IndexError: list index out of range at table_data[headers[len(table_data)]] = values

Tags: python, html, postgresql

I have this python script that reads a html file then creates a database table from that but I'm getting a `IndexError: list index out of range` error on line `table_data[headers[len(table_data)]] = values` I haven't worked much with python a lot but I've tried stuff with the for loop and the `len(table_data)`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify the path to your HTML file
html_file_path = 'C:/Users/tom/service/soc/Soc.html'

# Read the contents of the HTML file
with open(html_file_path, 'r') as file:
    html = file.read()

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all the tables in the HTML
tables = soup.find_all('table')

# Iterate over the tables
for table in tables:
    # Find the table's ID attribute
    table_id = table.get('id')

    # Extract the table headers
    headers = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('thead').find_all('th')]

    # Create a dictionary to store the table data
    table_data = {}

    # Iterate over the table rows
    for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
        # Extract the row cells
        cells = row.find_all('td')

        # Extract the cell values
        values = [cell.get_text().strip() for cell in cells]

        # Store the values with their corresponding headers in the dictionary
        table_data[headers[len(table_data)]] = values

    # Generate the PostgreSQL table script
    create_table_script = f"CREATE TABLE {table_id} (/n"
    for header, values in table_data.items():
        create_table_script += f"    {header} {', '.join(values)},/n"
    create_table_script = create_table_script.rstrip(',/n') + "/n);/n"

    # Print the table script
    print(create_table_script)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a full error message, but I think I see the problem. I'll make the assumption that `table_data` and `headers` are two related list of the same length. Remember that list indexes start with zero, therefore `len(lst)` returns the number above the number of the last index.

To illustrate:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst[len(lst)])  # IndexError: list index out of range
```

Assuming `headers` and `table_data` are of the same length, `len(table_data)` returns a number out of the range of both lists. If you were trying to get the last item in the list, just use `lst[-1]`.